# Error while converting C# date string into swift3 date

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

In one of my app i am getting date from an RESTful api as "04112017182149".

I tried to convert it into swift date for my internal user as shown in below snippet.

```
let receivedDate = "04112017182149"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" 
print((dateFormatter.date(from: receivedDate))!)
```

It is throwing a fatal error as Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value.

I had tried to change date formatter string as "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" but no use.

Comment: *Maybe* you should try to create a format that *actually* matches the data `04112017182149` you receive.

Comment: @luk2302 thats where i am facing the problem i don't have the exact idea to do it.

Comment: Look at the date format. Are there any hyphens in the date string...? And is the year (`yyyy`) at the beginning of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct date format is

```
ddMMyyyyHHmmss
```

Comment: Note that setting the date formatter locale to "en_US_POSIX" it is required to parse that string otherwise it will crash the app if the user changes the time format 12-24h or if it changes due to the device locale lettings.